# HTML / Javascript: Send field only if it changed

Tags: javascript, forms, http-post

I have a form with text-entry fields. Because database-operations are expensive, I use this method to check for changes:

```
<input type=text name=myinput value="Current text">
<input type=hidden name=myinput_original value="Current text">
```

This way I can compare myinput with myinput_original on the server and decide whether to check/update the database.

This is of course quite some overhead (basically doubling the data that is sent from/to the server) just to check for changes.

Currently the data is sent 4 times (twice from server to client, twice from client to server). I would like to reduce that to 1 - 2 times (if no change is done, data is sent only once to client and nothing is sent back; if a change occurs, data is sent only once to client and only once back to server).

I would like to optimize this with Javascript, so that if the user leaves the text as-is, *nothing* is transmitted to the sever (i.e. the field "myinput" is deleted from the POST request) and the text is only transmitted if there was a change in it (i.e. normal HTML-behavior). This way the server would only get the changed values.

How can that be done in Javascript?

Comment: Can you show the javascript you have on submit so that we can suggest the changes to it. I'd suggest you remove the element on checking the values on submit

Comment: Currently there is no Javascript (related to the form) on the client-side, it's just pure HTML as I have posted above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach event listeners for `focusout` (respectively `blur`) and compare the value to your original input data. If those two values match, nothing was changed.

```
document.getElementByName( 'myinput' ).addEventListener( 'focusout', function( event ) {
    if( document.getElementByName( 'myinput_original' ).value !== this.value ) {
        alert( 'new value differs' );
    };
}, false);
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/faphygty/

Comment: OK, that way I can check for changes, but how do I remove "myinput" from the POST request if no changes have been entered? (And of course that must also happen if the user never enters the text field.)

Comment: And I would also like to drop the "myinput_original" field because that doubles the data sent from server to client. Currently the data is sent 4 times (twice from server to client, twice from client to server). I would like to reduce that to 1 (if no change is done, data is sent once to client and nothing is sent back) to 2 (if a change occurs, data is sent once to client and once back to server).

Comment: To answer that, you would need to provide the source code which actually collects the (form) data.

Comment: There is no JS-code involved, it just sends "myinput" and "myinput_original" and I do a simple ´if ($_REQUEST['myinput'] != $_REQUEST['myinput_original'])´ on the server. I want to move this logic from the server (PHP in my case) to the client (Javascript).